# Todo validation failed: description: Path `description` is required., title: Path `title` is required

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

Following a youtube tutorial but getting a Validation error i.e ValidationError: Todo validation failed: title: Path `title` is required.

**user_model.ts**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

interface Todo_I {
    title: string;
    description: string;
}

interface TodoDocument extends mongoose.Document {
    title: string;
    description: string;
}

const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,

    },
});

interface todoModelInteface extends mongoose.Model<TodoDocument> {
    set(x: Todo_I): TodoDocument;
}

todoSchema.statics.set = (x: Todo_I) => {
    return new Todo();
}

const Todo = mongoose.model<TodoDocument, todoModelInteface>(
    "Todo",
    todoSchema,
)

Todo.set({
    title: "Some Title",
    description: "Some Description"
});

export { Todo };
```

**routes.ts**

```
import express, { Request, Response } from "express"
import { Todo } from "../models/user_model";

const router = express.Router()
router.post('/add', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { title, description } = req.body;
    const dataItem = Todo.set({ title, description });

    await dataItem.save();
    return res.status(200).json({
        data: dataItem,
    })
});

export { router };
```

**app.ts**

```
import express, { Request, Response } from "express"
import { router } from "./routes/routes";
import dotenv from "dotenv"
const { mongoose } = require("mongoose");

dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(
    process.env.MONGODB_URL as string,
    {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
    },
    ()=>{
        console.log("Db Connected!!!")
    }
)

app.use("/", router)

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Sever is rocking at 8080");
})
```

**Data which I am posting using PostMan**

```
{
    "title": "Some Title",
    "description": "Some Description"
}
```

**Error Screenshot**

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: please put a console.log in routes.ts to checking whether you got title and description or not, after destructring from res.body. and why the error is not about title, because both are the same, check the spelling of description maybe it is related to something like that.

Comment: The error is related to both i.e title and description. Still now can't get the solution. I have checked the spelling, and it is correct. Any further solutions you have?

Comment: and yes I am getting the res.body as I console logged it but don't know why getting the validationError

Comment: I think the error is related to your mongoose types...the types you use. so maybe it could be a start to remove the type and just start it and then gradually add your types

Comment: changed the routes.ts file to:
`router.post("/add", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const data = req.body;
    const todo = new Todo({
        title: data.title,
        description: data.description,
    })
    const response = await todo.save();
    res.status(200).json({
        message: "Todo Added Successfully",
        data: response
    })
})`
and the problem got fixed